# What is the way of adding a word to the line below using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression in python to add {\an8} in the start of every line below the lines contains the two words 'position:50.00%' and 'line:10.00%' at the same time, in a format like this one, thanks.

```
file_content = re.sub(r'line:10.00%[^\n]*(\n*)([\w\W .,:%])', r'\1{\\an8}\2', file_content)
```

Like this example:

```
00:05:31.957 --> 00:05:34.835  position:50.00%,start  align:start size:25.24%  line:10.00%
{\an8}Not yet.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
(.*\bposition\b:50\.00%.*\bline\b:10\.00%)\s*(.*)
```

Replacing with:

```
\1\n{\\an8}\2
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/OJ9p47/1).

---

In **Python**:

```
import re

mystring = '''00:05:31.957 --> 00:05:34.835  position:50.00%,start  align:start size:25.24%  line:10.00%
Not yet.'''

print(re.sub(r'(.*\bposition\b:50\.00%.*\bline\b:10\.00%)\s*(.*)',r'\1\n{\\an8}\2',mystring))
```

Prints:

```
00:05:31.957 --> 00:05:34.835  position:50.00%,start  align:start size:25.24%  line:10.00%
{\an8}Not yet.
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regular expressions.

```
previous_line_matched = False

for line in input:
    if previous_line_matched:
        print '{\\an8}' + line
    else:
        print line

    if 'position:50.00%' in line and 'line:10.00%' in line:
        previous_line_matched = True
    else:
        previous_line_matched = False
```

Comment: You can replace the last four lines with `previous_line_matched='position:50.00%' in line and 'line:10.00%' in line`. And if you want to be really fancy, you can replace the lines above with `print('{\\an8}'*previous_line_matched+line)`.